# React Native Image fetches from origin even when cached

Tags: react-native

Using React Native's `Image` component, I notice that after reloading the app the images are fetched from origin again although they're being cached.

I can see before loading the image that it's cached by doing

```
ImageReact.queryCache([props.source as string]).then((res) => {
  console.log(props.source, res); // prints "memory/disk"
});
```

and I see the requests firing using a HTTP proxy such as Proxyman or Flipper.

My server returns the image with proper `Cache-Control` headers, and I tried setting up the Image like so:

```
<Image
  style={{ height: 300, width: 300 }}
  source={{
    cache: 'force-cache', // tried them all
    uri: 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/338/200/200.jpghmac=5S5SeR5xW8mbN3Ml7wTTJPePX392JafhcFMGm7IFNy0'
  }}
></Image>
```

Comment: Can you share http headers for image? `uri` is correct? It seems to end with `jpghmac=5S5SeR5xW8mbN3Ml7wTTJPePX392JafhcFMGm7IFNy0` or it's `.jpg?hmac=5S5SeR5xW8mbN3Ml7wTTJPePX392JafhcFMGm7IFNy0`

Comment: I can put any other image url and it will act the same. Regardless, `queryCache` tells me it's cached, but it still re-fetches it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make a caching system with  'react-native-fs', it's a really nice feature to chack if the image is cached or not

Comment: Do you have any docs that explain this? The RN documentation doesn't mention in any part that caching should manually be implemented, nor provides methods to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is a cache miss due to the `hmac` token.

```
200.jpg?hmac=5S5SeR5xW8mbN3Ml7wTTJPePX392JafhcFMGm7IFNy0
```

Loading the same image with a different `hmac`/`token` will result in a cache miss. Native `<image>` does not support adding headers to image requests. You can try using [Fast Image](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) that supports authorization tokens.

```
<FastImage
  source={{
    uri: 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/338/200/200.jpg',
    headers:{ Authorization: 'someToken' },
    priority: FastImage.PriorityNormal
  }}
/>
```

Comment: I tried different images, this one is purely hardcoded for the sake of giving an example. The hmac never changes. 

We had to strip out Fast Image from our app because this library is poorly written and causes extensive memory leaks in prod.